# SPService arrange choice

Tags: 2007

I am using the SPService Sparrangechoice, it seems to work only for the first column and I cant seem to make it work for multiple columns

CODE:

```
<script src="/sites/eservices/SiteAssets/2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sites/eservices/SiteAssets/1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sites/eservices/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/sites/eservices/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
       alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());
       $().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices({
             listName:"test",                  
             columnName: "Option1",
             perRow: 12,
             randomize: false
       }); 
       alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());

       $().SPServices.SPArrangeChoices({
             listName:"test",                  
             columnName: "Option2",
             perRow: 4,
             randomize: false
       }); 
       alert($().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite());
  });
```

---

It is alerting 4 times which is true but not changing anything but the first column.

Comment: First thing, you don't need to attach two JS file of SPServices library. Either you can attach minified version or full version.

Comment: Second thing, your 1.js and 2.js, what are they? Are they jQuery library or what? Before DOM ready method you must need to reference jQuery library.